# R Parse data from from vertical list in text file separated by variable headers

Tags: r, parsing, text, data-structures

I am reading a standard text data file (Gait Cycle Data) which consists of the following format where `!` is used to specify that the text following it is a variable name and this is followed on subsequent lines by the mean (m) and standard deviation (s) data for that variable. Variables can be scalars, vectors or tensors.

```
#Some header lines
.
.
#in these variable names below the N just refers to the N used to compute mean and SD
#not the number of data points in the variable
!ScalarVariable1 N1 
m1 s1
!ScalarVariable2 N2
m2 s2
!VectorVariable3 N3
m3_1 s3_1
m3_2 s3_2
.
.
m3_100 s3_100
!VectorVariable4 N4
m4_1 s4_1
m4_2 s4_2
.
.
m4_100 s4_100
```

I am trying to find a good way to read the variable names and store the data in a dataframe(s) or individual arrays or (ideally I think) a structure. Dataframe storage is tricky because lengths vary: as shown there are scalars of length 1, there are normalized vectors of a known length (here 100), but there is also another class of vectors all of length N which are dependent upon the length of time the trial took. Finally there are also tensors, some with 3 columns of data, some with 6, and these also have both means and standard deviations.

I am using `readLines()` to import the files, which gives me each line of text in a single array. In matlab when I tackled this I read the data as lines of text exactly as `readLines()` provides, then looped through this array to count number of lines between variable names by detecting `!`, stored an index list of how many values were associated with each header, then went back and read in the data into a structure form using variable names (e.g. `GCD.velocity`). I'm brand new to R and have no idea how to approach this parsing problem. Just looking for help getting started in the right direction even if means only dealing with the known array lengths of 100 for now. Thanks.

Here are some sample lines from the file which cover all types of data and headers. Starts with all headers, followed by scalar, then vector, 12 column tensor, 6 column tensor (--- just indicates separator to jump to new variable, not in the file):

```
#!DST
$REFERENCE 5
G:\Gait Data\2015\GCD\xxx_07.gcd : Left(Angles,Forces) : Right(Angles,Forces) : +X
G:\Gait Data\2015\GCD\xxx_05.gcd : Left(Angles,Forces) : Right(Angles,Forces):-X
G:\Gait Data\2015\GCD\xxx_10.gcd : Left(Angles,Forces) : Right(Angles,Forces):-X
G:\Gait Data\2015\GCD\xxx_12.gcd : Left(Angles,Forces) : Right(Angles,Forces):-X
G:\Gait Data\2015\GCD\xxx_13.gcd : Left(Angles,Forces) : Right(Angles,Forces) : +X
!Mass 5    
29.0000 0.0000
!Height 5
1310.0000 0.0000
!LeftLegLength 5
640.0000 0.0000
!LeftTrunkObliquity 5
5.4914 1.8161
4.9017 1.7414
4.3771 1.6795
3.9143 1.6484
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
!LeftGroundReaction-3-2 5
-9.8387 -3.3189 30.0240 0.000 0.000 0.0418 7.9230 4.3737 17.2863 0.000 0.000 0.2978
-56.6241 -14.5228 123.1434 0.000 0.000 0.0923 6.0863 7.5595 35.1965 0.000 0.000 0.3562
-40.9967 4.3286 255.1618 0.000 0.000 0.5213 11.8429 9.5473 49.7839 0.000 0.000 0.3331
-85.3239 8.8256 428.0071 0.000 0.000 0.7669 9.9698 14.0490 44.5523 0.000 0.000 0.5099
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
!RightPelvicOrigin-3 5
-446.5973 -2.6151 -22.3667 24.8248 8.4681 0.9047
-426.1199 -3.9391 -21.4263 23.8164 7.1312 0.7944
-407.3914 -4.9089 -19.4336 22.8752 6.0196 1.1956
-389.6329 -5.7206 -16.6267 22.0211 5.1385 1.7573
-373.1119 -6.4350 -13.3333 21.2372 4.5618 2.2868
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you show how you want the expecte doutput

Comment: can you please provide example input of tensors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some regular expressions and `R`'s built-in `read.table` function we can pull this off, you can then use `list2env` to get the variables into the global env i.e you'll have scalars as vectors and vectors/tensors as data.frames named with the same name in the file:

```r
library(stringr)
input <- readLines("example.file")
input <- input[-(1:grep("^!",input)[1]-1)]
input <- input[!grepl("^--+$", input)]
str_extract(grep("^!", input, value=T), "(?<=!)\\S+") -> cs

input.t <- lapply( str_split( paste0(input, collapse='\n') , "\n(?=!)")[[1]] , function(x){
            
            res <- read.table(text=str_replace(x, "![^\n]+\n", ""))
            if(nrow(res)==1) unlist(res, use.names=F) else res
})

setNames(input.t, cs) -> input.t

list2env(input.t, .GlobalEnv)
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
ScalarVariable1
#> [1] 0.3186621 0.3861956
ScalarVariable2
#> [1] 1.8439012 0.3019289
head(VectorVariable3)
#>           V1        V2
#> 1 -0.1964990 0.9647295
#> 2 -0.4015327 0.5645811
#> 3 -1.1161385 0.6641921
#> 4  0.7292709 1.6256362
#> 5  0.6351160 0.5434198
#> 6  0.8395378 1.2967163
```

Or just a complete `baseR` solution no need for `stringr`:

```r
input <- readLines("example.file")
input <- input[-(1:grep("^!",input)[1]-1)]
input <- input[!grepl("^--+$", input)]
sub("^!(\\S+) .*$", '\\1', grep("^!", input, value=T)) -> cs

input.t <- lapply( strsplit( paste0(input, collapse='\n') , "\n(?=!)", perl=T)[[1]] , function(x){
            
            res <- read.table(text=sub("![^\n]+\n", "",x ))
            if(nrow(res)==1) unlist(res, use.names=F) else res
})

setNames(input.t, cs)
$Mass
[1] 29  0

$Height
[1] 1310    0

$LeftLegLength
[1] 640   0

$LeftTrunkObliquity
      V1     V2
1 5.4914 1.8161
2 4.9017 1.7414
3 4.3771 1.6795
4 3.9143 1.6484

$`LeftGroundReaction-3-2`
        V1       V2       V3 V4 V5     V6      V7      V8      V9 V10 V11    V12
1  -9.8387  -3.3189  30.0240  0  0 0.0418  7.9230  4.3737 17.2863   0   0 0.2978
2 -56.6241 -14.5228 123.1434  0  0 0.0923  6.0863  7.5595 35.1965   0   0 0.3562
3 -40.9967   4.3286 255.1618  0  0 0.5213 11.8429  9.5473 49.7839   0   0 0.3331
4 -85.3239   8.8256 428.0071  0  0 0.7669  9.9698 14.0490 44.5523   0   0 0.5099

$`RightPelvicOrigin-3`
         V1      V2       V3      V4     V5     V6
1 -446.5973 -2.6151 -22.3667 24.8248 8.4681 0.9047
2 -426.1199 -3.9391 -21.4263 23.8164 7.1312 0.7944
3 -407.3914 -4.9089 -19.4336 22.8752 6.0196 1.1956
4 -389.6329 -5.7206 -16.6267 22.0211 5.1385 1.7573
5 -373.1119 -6.4350 -13.3333 21.2372 4.5618 2.2868
```

#### Note :

that this solution is column agnostic as it doesn't matter if you have 1000 columns or just one as long as they're separated by space. the separator can be set in the `read.table` call

Comment: can u add the input that caused the error @bmacwilliams

Comment: Thank you. I have added some samples from the file to respond to the comments. Regarding this solution, this reads the variable names correctly (cs variable) but it fails in the read.table, I get an error: 

Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, : line 1 did not have 8 elements 

Happy to send a sample file, as I don't see a way to attach one here, thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @bmacwilliams check my edited answer. the problem due to the references and separator line now I remove them the code works flawlessly